# php full text search not working properly, some time it searches the word and sometimes not

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, stop-words, match-against

hell friends i am using mysql fulltext search in Boolean mode for my mobile selling site, user can register their mobile for sell and there is search bar like google where we can search that mobile and get user's advertise.

problem is when user register their mobile at then some time full text can search that mobile from database and sometimes it cant, i tried by "repair table items;" then once it worked but again same problem"

eg i have listed samsung galaxy" then it cant search that mobile from db, then i tried by just "galaxy" keyword and i got it from database again i registerd samsung ace and search that mobile from search bar then it is retrived from db....some times it is searching items sometimes not .any solution plz??thanx in advance

i tried to off ft_stopword_word and ft_min_length  but it did not worked.

Comment: This is too little information to provide any help. What happens when the search doesn't work? Are you getting any errors? What are they?

Comment: no errors but i tried by searching "galaxy" keyword instead of samsung galaxy. then i got information from database.. then i tried Repair table items; and searched "samsung" then i got result from database. so what should be problem? i am really stuck at this point

Comment: That's really weird. Not sure what is going on

Comment: @Pekka any suggestion for this from your side can be helpful to me. i tried  ft_stopword_word and ft_min_length its not working.any possible suggestion? like indexing problem or any thing ?

Comment: @pekka i got solution, i have written ft_stop_word  and ft_min_length at last line of my.cnf file of mysql and i had two indexed columns so i droped one fulltext column and its working,but not in production because of my.cnf is write protected.

Comment: if u dont mind will u please check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655527/my-cnf-file-in-openshift-redhat-is-write-protected-then-how-to-edit-that-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your help, i got solution, there was problem at server side, i was using openshift server for hosting, when i change ft_min_word_len file then in again next restart it will default changes value to 4.. i reported bug and got this reply

```
      the "devenv" is a lightly built testing environment, a daily version.
       also we have other testing environment like INT and STG, i guess you may test 

       on them even on PR environment.
       INT -> is built from devenv;
        STG -> is built from INT;
```

generally, the INT version is older than devenv, and the STG version is older than INT
so if you test on INT and STG, we need to ensure the fixed is merged into them.
as i know, the devenv may be merged to PR environment till January 2014.

if possible,you can have a try on devenv.